# my logout of a user does not work in symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, logout

I can not disconnect.There I have a doctor space, and when I finish with this space, I click on a disconnect button, and it redirects me to the home page.Then I have a user who consults the profile of a doctor and then decides to make an appointment, and when he chooses his date and time and arrives on a page where he must be register or connect.When he chooses to connect and returns his login, clicks on login, it is supposed to be redirected to his patient area with the info of the appointment, but symfony tells me Acces Denied.And in the toolbar of symfony I see that I am logged as user doctor on which I was before and I disconnected.

**Security.yml**

```
   # app/config/security.yml

security:
    encoders:
         Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: sha512
         Doctix\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_PATIENT: ROLE_PATIENT
    ROLE_MEDECIN: ROLE_MEDECIN
    ROLE_STRUCTURE_SINITAIRE: ROLE_STRUCTURE_SINITAIRE
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_ADMIN]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    main:
        entity:
            class: Doctix\UserBundle\Entity\User
            property: username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern:  ^/
        anonymous: true
        provider:  main
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /


access_control:
   # - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/patient, roles: ROLE_PATIENT }
    - { path: ^/medecin, roles: ROLE_MEDECIN }
    - { path: ^/structure-sanitaire, roles: ROLE_STRUCTURE_SINITAIRE }
```

**Routing in my UserBundle and not the app/config.yml**

```
  #url de la connexion d'un utilisateur
  login:
     path: /login
    defaults: { _controller: DoctixUserBundle:Security:login }

 # url qui verifie l'authentification du user
  login_check:
     path: /login_check


  #url de deconnexion
    logout:
      path: /logout
```

Thanks.